# What is the purpose of creating multiple UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

For example in FirstViewController and I want to push SecondViewController, and I have a navigationController in FirstViewController, I could just push SecondViewController to it right?

Unless SecondViewController has another set of navigation hierarchy, then only it makes sense to create an another navigationController for it?

Answer (score 1):

FirstViewController doesn't have a navigation controller in it; *it is in* a navigation controller.

A navigation controller is a container. The navigation bar you see at the top belongs to the navigation controller. The content below that belongs to the view controller which is currently at the top of the navigation stack (except the toolbar, if you're showing that).

You can't actually push another navigation controller onto the stack - this raises an exception. So unless you've got a tabbed app structure, most apps will have only one navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

lol wut?

Right click on the body of the Navigation Controller, drag the blue line to FirstViewController. Choose "Root View Controller" for the popup.

Right click on the body of FirstViewController and drag it to SecondViewController, Choose "push".

Click on the lines between the first and second view controllers, this is a Segue. Give the segue a unqiue Identifier like "firstToSecondSegue".

From within FirstVewController.m you can programmatically push SecondViewController onto the Navigation stack with

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"firstToSecondSegue" sender:self];
```

[image: storyboard]